# Error while installing Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 10.10, with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 to be able to install Rails 4.0.
My RVM version is the latest stable. I've also tried `apt-get -y update`.

`rvm list known` shows **[ruby-]1.9.3[-p448]** in the list

Please advise :)

```
rvm install 1.9.3-p448

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/10.10/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p448.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.

Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/txwikinger/php5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/txwikinger/php5.2/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick Release
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/ ./ Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/ ./ Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

Comment: Ubuntu 10 is a little bit long in the tooth. Can you upgrade?

Comment: Update to 12.04 will probably help.

Comment: I have never upgraded, and I feel that it is a task too big at the moment, especially to take all the apps offline :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

switch RVM Autolibs to `read-fail`:

```
rvm autolibs read-fail
```

it will tell RVM to not install/update anything and only fail telling you what is missing for you, from here on it's your choice if you want to install the missing dependencies (most likely you do), or to ignore the dependencies and let RVM know you do not want to know that something is missing with:

```
rvm autolibs read-only
```

it will tell RVM to not install/update anything and only use what is already installed, no fail will occur, just a warning will be displayed that something is missing.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried installing it with this command?

sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3

Comment: Will RVM be able to pick up this installed version?

Comment: Bad idea! You should never install ruby without a version manager like rvm or rbenv

Comment: If you are only planning on using one version for development why does it matter?